# C# Object Problem - Can't Solve It

Tags: c#

I'm getting the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. I've tried looking at similar problems but genuinely cannot see what the problem is with my program. The line of code that I am having an error with is:

```
labelQuestion.Text = table.Rows[0]["Question"].ToString();
```

Here is my code in its entirety:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Quiz_Test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    String chosenAnswer, correctAnswer;
    DataTable table;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //declare connection string using windows security
        string cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Hannah\\Desktop\\QuizQuestions.accdb";

        //declare Connection, command and other related objects
        OleDbConnection conGet = new OleDbConnection(cnString);
        OleDbCommand cmdGet = new OleDbCommand();

        //try
        //{
        //open connection
        conGet.Open();
        //String correctAnswer;

        cmdGet.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdGet.Connection = conGet;

        cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM QuizQuestions ORDER BY rnd()";

        OleDbDataReader reader = cmdGet.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        labelQuestion.Text = table.Rows[0]["Question"].ToString();
        radioButton1.Text = table.Rows[0]["Answer 1"].ToString();
        radioButton2.Text = table.Rows[0]["Answer 2"].ToString();
        radioButton3.Text = table.Rows[0]["Answer 3"].ToString();
        radioButton4.Text = table.Rows[0]["Answer 4"].ToString();
        correctAnswer = table.Rows[0]["Correct Answer"].ToString(); ;


        conGet.Close();

    }

    private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Hannah\\Desktop\\QuizQuestions.accdb";

        //declare Connection, command and other related objects
        OleDbConnection conGet = new OleDbConnection(cnString);
        OleDbCommand cmdGet = new OleDbCommand();

        //try
        {
            //open connection
            conGet.Open();

            cmdGet.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmdGet.Connection = conGet;

            cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM QuizQuestions ORDER BY rnd()"; // select all columns in all rows

            OleDbDataReader reader = cmdGet.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();

            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                chosenAnswer = reader["Answer 1"].ToString();
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                chosenAnswer = reader["Answer 2"].ToString();
            }
            else if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                chosenAnswer = reader["Answer 3"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                chosenAnswer = reader["Answer 4"].ToString();
            }

            if (chosenAnswer == reader["Correct Answer"].ToString())
            {
                //chosenCorrectly++;
                MessageBox.Show("You have got this answer correct");
                //label2.Text = "You have got " + chosenCorrectly + " answers correct";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("That is not the correct answer");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I realise the problem isn't too big but I can't see how my declaration timings are wrong

Comment: I don't see where you are populating your data table.  It is null.

Comment: did you try setting a break point on that line of code (press f9) and then hover your mouse over the various identifiers - see which one comes up null...

Comment: You are missing the part where you assign your result set to your DataTable.  table is unassigned.

Comment: There is no connection between your reader and your datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after you call ExecuteReader () in Form1_Load you need

```
table = new DataTable();
table.Load (reader);
```

Answer (score 5):

You never initialize `table`, so it will be `null` when you try to access its `Rows` property.

You don't actually need the `DataTable` in this instance, though. You can access the properties directly from the `OleDbDataReader` (which you *do* initialize.) See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for details (look at the `Get***()` family of methods.)

Something like:

```
labelQuestion.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Question"));
```

And so forth for the rest of the columns.

If you do choose to use `table`, then omit the `reader.Read()` line and add:

```
table = new DataTable();
table.Load(reader);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your table is not initialized. Therefore, when you try to access `table.row[0]` you get this error message.

And If there was no question column, you would probably get an error like

```
Column ‘Question’ does not belong to table.
```

Hence, at this point it is not ok. to say whether there is 'Question' column or not. First, you need to fill your table.

Comment: Table isn't even initialized.

Answer (score 0):

**Error object reference Null:**

```
try
{
    OleDbCommand com;
    //   OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
    cn.Open();

    string str = "select *from DatabaseLogin where user_id='" + textBox2.Text + "'";
    com = new OleDbCommand(str, cn);
    OleDbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(reader["stckdemge"].ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(" " + ex);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Either the table has no rows, or there is no "Question" column, or that the column has a Null value in it.

Consider breaking the assignment up into multiple steps to help you diagnose the issue.

EDIT:
Or, as sharper eyes have already noted, it's because you've not assigned anything to 'table' (d'oh).

The comment about breaking up the assignment is a useful diagnostic method, though.